# How can I select items from one sql table that don't appear in another table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a Customer table which has an ID. Each Customer entry has a Design which is stored in a Design table (it contains the CustomerID to reference).

In my scenario, a Customer can have several Designs and sometimes no Designs. How could I select Customers that only have Designs?

I've tried doing an Inner Join like this but I still get too many records since a Customer can have many Designs:

```
Select * from Customer
Inner Join Design
On Design.CustomerID = Customer.ID
Where Design.CustomerID is not null
```

Comment: how you storing the empty desings ? null or what ?

Comment: Sounds like you want to use `DISTINCT` and then supply the column names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`*` select all records of all tables. Use `tablename.*` to select only all records of a specific table.

```
Select Customer.*
from Customer
Inner Join Design
On Design.CustomerID = Customer.ID
```

But actually you are always better off by explicitly defining which columns you need. So use

```
Select Customer.ID, Customer.Col2, Customer.Col3
from Customer
Inner Join Design On Design.CustomerID = Customer.ID
group by Select Customer.ID, Customer.Col2, Customer.Col3
```

And when you use an `inner join` then only the records will be returned that actually have a link to the joined table - so your `where` clause is obsolete.

Comment: yeah, but I'm still getting multiple records since the relationship of Customer to Design is one to many. thanks

Comment: can I use DISTINCT to get just one?

Comment: Yes, either use `distinct` or `group by` all columns you select.

Answer (score 0):

i guess you storing an empty strings in your database .

try that

```
  Select * from Customer
  Inner Join Design
  On Design.CustomerID = Customer.ID
  Where Design.CustomerID is not null
  AND Design.CustomerID != ''
  GROUP BY Customer.ID
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do a [`where exists`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html)

```
select * from Customer
where exists (select 1 from Design where CustomerId = Customer.ID)
```